# What is the Big-O of this pseudo code? I need a proper explain also

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o, pseudocode

This is the pseudo code that i want to calculate time complexity ,i think it is a binary search algorithm but i fail when calculating the complexity because it is reducing logarithamic.

```
   USE variables half-array,found,middle element
   SET half-array=initial array;
   SET found=True;

 Boolean SearchArray(half-array)

   find middle element in half-array;
   Compare search key with middle element;
   IF middle element==search key THEN
           SET found=True;
   ELSE
        IF search key< middle element THEN
          SET half-array=lower half of initial array;
        ELSE
          SET half-array=upper half of initial array;


 SearchArray(half-array)
```

Comment: Are you only running the method once, or are you running it recursively?

Comment: run it recursively

Comment: its binary search, log(n)

Comment: It looks like you are running this method recursively, and with each iteration you are reducing the number of elements being searched by half. This is going to be a logarithmic reduction, i.e. O(log n).

Comment: What is the answer? Is it O(log n)

Comment: @kalsaraMagamage as Rion and nafas stated, yes it is

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369563/difference-between-on-and-ologn-which-is-better-and-what-exactly-is-olo  Think of O(n) as a single enumeration on a List of size n. O(log n) would be when the algorithm is much more efficient and doesn't enumerate the entire List, but uses logic to find the answer quicker as in a binary search

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to calculate binary search complexity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185079/how-to-calculate-binary-search-complexity)

Comment: It is `O(42)`. Why? Because `42` is the answer of all questions available in the universe.

Comment: Rote learning of answers one question at a time will not teach you. You need to purchase and study https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are running this method recursively, and with each iteration you are reducing the number of elements being searched by half. This is going to be a logarithmic reduction, i.e. **O(log n)**.

Since you are reducing your elements by half each time, you need to determine how many executions will be needed to reduce it to a single element, which [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8185382/557445) provides a proof or if you are a more visual person, you can use the following diagram from [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13093274/557445):

[image]

Comment: can i write the answer like this,   log/ln N

Comment: You would simply write it as `O(logN)`. Big O notation generally ignores any coefficients, so if there were any (e.g. `O(2N)` == `O(N)`).

Comment: Nope, you would ignore any specifics regarding bases as well (e.g. `O(log2N)` == `O(logN)`). Exponents are really the only exception to this, as `O(N^2)` is very different from `O(N^3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,It is indeed a binary search algorithm.The reason why it is called a 'binary' search is because,if you would have noticed,after each iteration,your problem space is reduced by roughly half (I say roughly because of the floor function).
So now,to find the complexity,we have to devise a recurrence relation,which we can use to determine the worst-case time complexity of binary-search.

Let T(n) denote the number of comparisons binary search does for n elements.In the worst case,no element is found.Also,to make our analysis easier,assume that n is a power of 2.

**BINARY SEARCH:**

1. When there is a single element,there is only one check,hence T(1) = 1.
2. It calculates the middle entry then compares it with our key.If it is equal to the key,it returns the index,otherwise it halves the range by updating upper and lower bounds such that n/2 elements are in the range.
3. We then check only one of the two halves,and this is done recursively until a single element is left.

Hence,we get the recurrence relation:

**T(n) = T(n/2) + 1**

Using the Master Theorem,we get the time complexity to be **T(n) ∈ Θ(log n)**

Also refer : [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in saying that this algorithm is Binary Search (compare your pseudo code to the pseudo code on this Wikipedia page: [Binary Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Procedure))

That being the case, this algorithm has a worst case time complexity of O(log n), where n is the number of elements in the given array. This is due to the fact that in every recursive call where you don't find the target element, you divide the array in half.

This reduction process is logarithmic because at the end of this algorithm, you will have reduced the list to a single element by dividing the number of elements that still need to be checked by 2 - the number of times you do that is roughly equivalent (see below) to the number of times you would have to multiply 2 by itself to obtain a number equal to the size of the given array.

*I say *roughly* above because the number of recursive calls made is always going to be an integral value, whereas the power you would have to raise 2 to will not be an integer if the size of the given list is not a power of two.